# Welcome message doesn't send?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, welcome-file

Whenever someone joins, the error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')` appears in the console. I have also correctly selected all the intents that you need for a welcome system or for a welcome message
If I do `welcome Channel.send` at the end, `send` is also displayed there as a possible suggestion!
Here is the code can someone help me?

```
const client = require("../index");
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const welcomeSchema = require("../models/welcomschema")
const Canvas = require("canvas");

var welcomeCanvas ={};
welcomeCanvas.create = Canvas.createCanvas(1024, 500)
welcomeCanvas.context = welcomeCanvas.create.getContext('2d')
welcomeCanvas.context.font = '72px Arial';
welcomeCanvas.context.fillStyle = '#ffffff';

Canvas.loadImage('https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/964174410510655538/964582440993706044/schwarz.jpeg').then(async (img) => {
    welcomeCanvas.context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 1024, 500)
    welcomeCanvas.context.fillText("welcome", 360, 360);
    welcomeCanvas.context.beginPath();
    welcomeCanvas.context.arc(512, 166, 128, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    welcomeCanvas.context.stroke();
    welcomeCanvas.context.fill()
})

client.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
    const guildData = welcomeSchema.findOne({ guildid : member.guild.id })
    if(guildData) {
    const welcomeid = guildData.channel
    let welcomeChannel = client.channels.cache.get(welcomeid);
    const welcomeText = guildData.welcometext
    let canvas = welcomeCanvas;
    canvas.context.font = '42px sans-serif',
    canvas.context.textAlign = 'center';
    canvas.context.fillText(member.user.tag, 512, 410)
    canvas.context.beginPath()
    canvas.context.arc(512, 166, 119, 0, Math.PI * 2, true)
    canvas.context.closePath()
    canvas.context.clip()
    await Canvas.loadImage(member.user.displayAvatarURL({format: 'png', size: 1024}))
    .then(img => {
        canvas.context.drawImage(img, 393, 47, 238 ,238);
    })
    let atta = new Discord.MessageAttachment(canvas.create.toBuffer(), `welcome-${member.user.tag}.png`)
    try {
        welcomeChannel.send({
            content: `<@${member.id}>, ${welcomeText}`, atta
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
})
```

Here is the welcome Schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

let Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    guildid : String,
    channel : String,
    welcometext : String 
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("welcome", Schema)
```

Comment: The error indicates that `welcomeChannel` is undefined, which means that the Map `client.channels.cache` does not contain a key with the value `welcomeid` (=`guildData.channel`). Not knowing how the Map is built, it's impossible to provide further analysis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Change the following line:

```js
const guildData = welcomeSchema.findOne({ guildid : member.guild.id })
```

- To

```js
const guildData = await welcomeSchema.findOne({ guildid : member.guild.id })
```

Awaiting the `<Schema>.findOne` will not return an `undefined` value